# Linq/Lambda code works in vb but not c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

The following works in VB..

```
Dim q = allValues.GroupBy(Function(u) u.R).Select(Function(grp) grp).OrderByDescending(Function(a) a.Count).ToList
```

But not in C#..

```
dynamic q = allValues.GroupBy(u => u.R).Select(grp => grp).OrderByDescending(a => a.Count).ToList;
```

"allValues" is a list of color of various pixels.  I'm trying to group the color R value and sort by the count descending to find the most used color.

I'm a noob to C# and Lambda.  This is also my first post to the site.  Thanks for any insite!

Comment: In C# it should be `.ToList()` note `()`

Comment: You have a typo. Instead of trying to call `ToList()` you are trying to access a non-existent property `ToList`

Comment: Note that by using `dynamic` instead of `var` you prevented the compiler from catching the error immediately. In fact, IntelliSense would have caught it and warned you about both `ToList` and `Count`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a.Count` is a method, it needs parentheses -

```
.OrderByDescending(a => a.Count())
```

So does `ToList()` for that matter.

And a couple of little side issue:

- `Select(grp => grp)` is pointless, you can just remove that bit.
- The result does not need to be `dynamic` - you can just use `var`.

Answer (score 4):

The right syntax is

```
var q = allValues // probably you mean "var" instead of "dynamic"
   .GroupBy(u => u.R)
   .Select(grp => grp) // that's redundant, you can remove it
   .OrderByDescending(a => a.Count())
   .ToList();
```

note `()` after `Count` and after `ToList`. "()" means that you *call* the method.

Comment: You could consider `dynamic` to be problematic. If it was `var`, Intellisense and the compiler would have caught the typos

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: thank you, it definitely should be "var", I've edited the answer.